# Database Design - Dependency between records using EF CORE

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm creating a database using Code-First approach with EF Core 5.0.
I have a problem related to model entity in order to represent relationship between two records of the same table. Following an example:

Table LAWS

- Law Id 1 has a dependency with Law 2. It is single (law depends only to maximum one another law) and bidirectional, so also Law 2 has a dependency to Law 1.

How to model this situation? I tried:

- using a property inside the entity Law called LinkedLawId, but I had problem related to circular dependency;

```
public class Law {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? LinkedLawId { get; set; }
    public Law LinkedLaw { get; set; }
}
```

- using a second table where I store the two ids of the related laws, but also in this case I had a problem of circular dependency. Something like that:

```
public class LinkedLaw 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FirstLawId { get; set; }
    public int SecondLawId { get; set; }
    public Rule FirstLaw { get; set; }
    public Rule SecondLaw { get; set; }
}
```

Perhaps the design or the configuration with Fluent API is bad.

N.B. problem of circular dependency are shown when the seeding process starts (EF Core seeding data).

Comment: There's no fundamental problem with circular dependencies.  You simply must disable cascading deletes, and not try to add a cycle in a single call to SaveChanges().

Comment: With linking table there is no circular dependency (there are multiple cascade paths, but that's SqlServer specific issue). However the bidirectional requirement is not easy to model/enforce in relational database (hence with EF Core which even though theoretically supports non relational database, most of the concepts it's built around are coming from relational databases).